# AWS RDS update failing after restore from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i created a RDS in AWS through serverless.
First it is don't have encryption so i took a manual snapshot of rds instance and created encrypted snapshot from that.

Now in serverless i changed like below.
1. i removed rds instance from aws stack (added a condition on RDS instance and re-design the template without rds)
2. Now i am re-deploying data base with DBSnapshotIdentifier.
3. Now if i try to re-run the stack with out DBSnapshotIdentifier it is failing.

Here my question is, Once if we use DBSnapshotIdentifier every time we need to provide that?

Note : i created a fresh stack with out providing DBSnapshotIdentifier created fine.
 i re-run the deployment with out  providing DBSnapshotIdentifier it's working.
 The above case also similar i guess.

Please go through below yaml you will understand what i did on rds

createRDSInstance : it is used to create or remove rds from template.(from stack)

dbSnapshot: it is used to the way of deployement snapshot or simple update

```
testCrid:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"      
DependsOn: "testVPC"
Condition: createRDSInstance
Properties:
  DBInstanceIdentifier: "Crid-${self:custom.arguments.stage}"
  DBName: 
    Fn::If: [ dbSnapshot, "${self:custom.arguments.database}", Ref: "AWS::NoValue" ] 
  Engine: "MySQL"
  EngineVersion: "5.7.16"
  DBInstanceClass: ${self:custom.arguments.dbInstanceClass}
  MasterUsername: test
  MasterUserPassword: ${self:custom.arguments.password}
  PubliclyAccessible: ${self:custom.arguments.public}
  DBParameterGroupName:
    Ref: "CridParameterGroup"
  VPCSecurityGroups:
    - Ref: "PrivateSubnetDBSecurityGroup"
  DBSubnetGroupName:
    Ref: "CridSubnetGroup"
  AllocatedStorage: '5'
  StorageType: "gp2"
  StorageEncrypted: true
  MultiAZ: true
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: 
    Fn::If: [ dbSnapshot, Ref: "AWS::NoValue","${self:custom.arguments.dBSnapshotIdentifier}"]
```

Comment: What error are you getting when the stack creation fails when you re-run the stack with out *DBSnapshotIdentifier* in the 3rd step?

Comment: If i re-run without DBSnapshotIdentifier then template change will be there. Then in AWS it is trying to create new rds instance. But i provided same DBInstanceIdentifier in this case the error will be "Custom-named recourse replacing required ". If i comment DBInstanceIdentifier in the code then every template change AWS creating new instance and deleting old one ( but this is not good for production if some one forget to provide DBSnapshotIdentifier then AWS stack will create a complete brand new RDS instance and delete old instance)